# Exclude Sub Folder Within Directory C#

Tags: c#

I wanted to exclude a folder within directory when copying the directory to other location could anyone please help me out ?

```
string logZipTarget = "PangaeaLogs_Fail_" + currentLocation + "_" + classID + "_" + tracer + "_" +

DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy-HH-mm-ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".zip";

string buildTypeFile = @"C:\build.typ";

string journalFile = @"C:\Mavis\" + tracer + ".ejl";

string logsPath = @"C:\Pangaea\PangaeaFinancialLogs\"; //Path to copy directory to

File.Copy(buildTypeFile, logsPath + "build.typ", true);

File.Copy(journalFile, logsPath + tracer + ".ejl", true);                

Helper.DirectoryCopy(@"C:\Program Files\NCR\Pangaea\", logsPath, true);

executor.ZipFolder(logsPath, logZipTarget);
```

Inside this location **C:\Pangaea\PangaeaFinancialLogs\ApplicationData** i wanted to remove this folder **SessionBackup** but what is happening is it is copyin all the folders inside this location
 **string logsPath = @"C:\Pangaea\PangaeaFinancialLogs\";**

Comment: If(!currentFolder.Equals(NameOfFolderNotToInclude))
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"), true);

Comment: This is the code i have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Is currentFolder complete path or just the directory name?? if one variable has path and another just the name then it will not compare.. provided code is not enough to understand the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

From the bit of code provided in your comment I can only assume which classes your using. If I'm correct this should do the trick:

```
    DirectoryInfo currentFolder = new DirectoryInfo("");
    String NameOfFolderNotToInclude = "";

    if(currentFolder.Name != NameOfFolderNotToInclude) 
    {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(@"\\xxx\yyy", @"C:\bbb"), true);
    }
```

Always keep in mind that equals ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx)) if not overidden will always compare the actual objects for equality. In your case a string will never be the same as a DirectoryInfo and thus not be equal even if the DirectoryInfo is pointing at the location the string describes.

Comment: Hi Bechtel i have added my code above could you please suggest to that ?

Comment: @shashank most likely the solution I suggested has to be integrated in your Helper.DirectoryCopy method. If you can not edit this method to exclude the **SessionBackup** you will most likely have to copy everything and delete the directory afterwards. Or write your own recursive directory copy method which can exclude directories.